# Is there a reason for SQLite allowing me to filter a created column and PostgreSQL not

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I was wondering why is it that I could filter a created column in the WHERE clause when I thought that due to Order of execution It was not allowed. In SQLite I was able to filter a column that I created in the SELECT clause and in PostgreSQL it won't. Reason for this? I am confused and since I am new to SQL I want to truly understand this.

[SQLite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoqFf.png)

[PostrgeSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yw6Y.png)

I tried the same thing in PostgreSQL and nothing. Here are pictures.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).But to answer your question: RDBMSs have different functionality and syntax. What works in one is not guaranteed to work in any other. MySQL has lots of non-standard functionality that is not available elsewhere.

Comment: Different databases, different functionality. There is a overlap, but not 100%

Comment: 1) **Do not use images** for textual information, copy and paste as text. 2) Read [SELECT List](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST). The relevant part  *An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.*. 3) Also read the *Description* section that shows the general processing order of a query. You will see `WHERE` is run before the output rows are processed.